# ON/OFF button for Processing

Tags: arduino, processing

I can't seem to get the follow code right.

This is a basic program I'm using with Processing. I made the square change color when I click it, but I can't seem to get it to change back again when clicked for a second time.

It's basically a toggle button when I click the square and NOT when I release the mouse button. I'm trying to integrate it with Arduino, that's why there is the port write.

```java
boolean A = true;
int x = 50;
int y = 50;
int w = 100;
int h = 100;
import processing.serial.*;
Serial port;
int val;

void setup() {
    size(200, 200);
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(x, y, w, h);
    port = new Serial(this, 9600);
}

void draw() {
    background(255);
    if ((A) && (mousePressed) && ((mouseX > x) && (mouseX < x + w) &&
        (mouseY > y) && (mouseY < y + h))) { // If mouse is pressed,

        fill(40, 80, 90);
        A = !A;// change color and
        port.write("H"); // Send an H to indicate mouse is over square.
    }
    rect(50, 50, 100, 100); // Draw a square.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some example code that should do what you want. A few things to note:

The `draw()` function should only be used to actually draw your sketch, other code should be located elsewhere. It is called in a continuous loop to redraw the screen, so any extra code can slow down or even prevent the redrawing, which is undesirable.

You were on the right track with the `A` variable. I've renamed it to `squareVisible`. It is a boolean variable that indicates whether to draw the square or not. The `draw()` function checks it's state, and changes the fill to only draw the square if `squareVisible` is true.

The `mousePressed()` function is called by Processing when you click somewhere in the sketch. It is toggling the squareVisible variable.

The `mouseMoved()` function is called by Processing when you move the mouse without clicking, it is a better place to send serial output than the draw() function.

```
boolean squareVisible = true;
int x = 50;
int y = 50;
int w = 100;
int h = 100;
import processing.serial.*;
Serial port;
int val;

void setup() {
    size(200, 200);
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(x, y, w, h);

    port = new Serial(this, 9600);
}

void draw() {
    background(255);
    if (squareVisible) {
        fill(40, 80, 90);
    } else {
        fill(255, 0, 0);
    }
    rect(x, y, w, h); // Draw a square
}


void mousePressed() {
    if (((mouseX > x) && (mouseX < x + w) &&
            (mouseY > y) && (mouseY < y + h))) {
        // if mouse clicked inside square
        squareVisible = !squareVisible;  // toggle square visibility
    }
}

void mouseMoved() {
    if (((mouseX > x) && (mouseX < x + w) &&
            (mouseY > y) && (mouseY < y + h))) {
        port.write("H");                 // send an H to indicate mouse is over square
    }
}
```